# Exercise Book for multivariable Calculus

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

can anyone recommend a good exercise book for multivariable calculus. 
It should contain practical applications of

Fubini's Theorem,

Substitution for multiple variables,

Divergence theorem

etc.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: This does not fall under those tags. Please edit your questions so reference request is included instead

Comment: @VarunIyer Actually, if you read the [(reference-request)](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) tag's wiki, you'll see that it explicitly states that it shouldn't be used by itself.

Comment: my bad. next time i will take care . thanks

Answer (score 2):

Both have extensive lists of exercises:

*Schaum's Outline of Calculus*.  Has a chapter on double and iterated integrals.

*Schaum's Outline of Advanced Calculus*.  Has a chapter on multiple integrals.

Comment: thanks. do you also have a good recommendation for  integration on manifolds ?